# New-bought cushion not washable?

Tags: cleaning, clothing

So I've just returned home and bought this cushion. Really really soft, bright colours, I just love it. However, I noticed this label that says:

> Do Not Wash. Do Not Bleach. Line Dry. Do Not Iron. Do Not Dry Clean.

When I read `Do Not Wash`, I thought that I could dryclean the thing. However, in the end, it also says `Do Not Dry Clean`. Then how am I supposed to clean this thing? On further reading, I noticed a little note from the distributor (Miniso) writing:

> Brand: MINISO; Product name: cushion; Bar code: *something*; Material:
>   exterior: 95% polyester, 5% elastane; Insides: 100% polyester.
>   Caution: do not soak and do not brush. Do not bleach. Wash gently with
>   hands. Avoid direct sunlight.

So some questions from an oblivious new cushion customer here:

- It says `do not wash`, but it also says `wash gently with hands`. Well, I need to wash it **eventually**, so I assume we're gonna do it with hands. How do I wash things 'gently'?
- It also says `line dry` and I looked the term up. It means to literally dry the thing on a clothing line, thus **direct sunlight!** But it tells me to avoid direct sunlight. What? What should I do?

Could a cushion expert help me with this? The two notes are different. The first one is stitched to the cushion with the label MARVEL, the second one is sticked to a sort of distributor label sign.

For reference, the pillow is **extremely** similar to this one here: [link to Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BQFWDN2).

Comment: @Willeke Unfortunately, it's fully stitched. Why?

Comment: Cleaning instructions for the outer layer and for the filling may well be different, with a fully stitched on you need to follow the careful way for either one at the same time.

Comment: @Willeke Could you provide the answers to my questions, please? I'm not quite sure what you meant on your final comment.

Comment: Hi Richard, Welcome to lifehacks. This is not rocket science. Wash by hand (not in a washing machine) as you would with wool articles. Don't leave to soak as the colours will run. Wash in a basin of water by hand according to directions on container, rinse, squeeze out excess water, and hang up to drip-dry (not in a hot clothes dryer at above normal air temperatures.) Don't leave it for long periods in sunlight as the colours will fade.

Comment: Most clothing manufacturers tag their garments as "Dry Clean Only" to avoid litigation from badly maintained products. The label almost ensures that a professional will be the one cleaning the clothing. Almost all of the time it is unnecessary no matter the material.

Comment: Is it possible the colours will run? If so perhaps wash in cold water with a liquid wool detergent only and lay flat on a towel to dry with a towel inside.

Comment: "Line dry" does not mean putting it in the sun, it means hanging it to dry (as opposed to "lay flat to dry," another drying instruction).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your cushion is not a separate cover with a filling you can take out you need to clean such that both the cover and the filling can handle it.

The one line that confuses me more than any of the others is 'line dry' which indicates that you can get the cushion wet.

Keep the cushion dry as much as possible, use it for show rather than for cuddling with (if you want to keep it long.) Dust it, with a mild vacuum cleaner.
And when you need to clean it more than you can that way, you can try to use a damp cloth, the soap duds of a mild soap, (dish washing liquids is sometimes used for this) and gently clean the surface with it, not getting it wet enough to get the filling wet.
Then you can pin it to a line to dry, keeping it out of direct sunlight by having it 'hide' behind a bigger item or by being on a line which is in the shade. (Or keep it in a heated room.)

If the cushion was not expensive or is deemed to far dirty or wet to rescue with above method, just wash it whatever way, it might work out. Labels with wash instructions are mostly more careful than needed, as you might sue the producers if you follow instructions in it and damage the item.
I often ignore the labels for items I need to wash often. Most of the time it works out but sometimes you have to bin it. That is a risk you can take if you can not rescue it without taking that risk.

Comment: Normally, line dry means hang to drip-dry as opposed to using an electric/gas heated clothes dryer at higher than normal air temperature.

Answer (score 1):

Hand wash this pillow in the kitchen sink using Woolite or another liquid laundry detergent for use on “delicates.” There are a number of products marketed for use on infant clothing which would work well.

Fill the sink with enough warmish, tepid water to submerge the pillow at least halfway. Add about a capful detergent (follow label instructions, DO NOT OVERSOAP; it will make rinsing difficult). Agitate water until soap is distributed throughout. Water should feel slightly slippery but not “soapy.”

Submerge the pillow, but not to saturation. Squeeze the pillow with your hands over all material. Continue to squeeze and release until you see the water change color from the release of dirt and oils.

Drain soapy water. Squeeze excess water out of pillow. Refill sink with clear, cool water and repeat the squeeze/release to rinse out soap. Two rinses may be needed.

In the sink, squeeze out as much water as possible without wrenching or twisting the fabric. Shake out excess water (outside is best). Wrap wet pillow in a clean, dry towel and apply pressure to absorb remaining water. When you hold the pillow aloft, there should be no dripping water. If there is, repeat process with towel.

To dry: Fluff pillow and distribute the stuffing, redistribute any clumps. Place on drying rack indoors or in any area without direct sunlight (to avoid damage from fading). 

[image: drying rack]

Check drying by fluffing. Drying time will vary; leave overnight for best results.

When I need something quickly or if it’s difficult to dry (without using a dryer), I place a fan near my drying rack. Works well. Good luck.